# git add warning about line endings, core.autocrlf is false

Tags: windows, git, line-endings

Everything I've read online tells me this should not be possible:

```
C:\Users\eric_\Code\range-v3>git add conanfile.py.in
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in conanfile.py.in.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

C:\Users\eric_\Code\range-v3>git config core.autocrlf
false
```

Why can't I get git to ignore line endings in files?

EDIT: I have a `.gitattributes` file in that directory, with the following:

```
*.hpp text
*.cpp text
*.txt text
*.html text
*.md text
*.yml text
*.xml text
*.in text
.gitattributes text
.gitignore text

*.cmd -text
*.sln -text
*.vcxproj -text
*.vcxproj.filters -text
```

Comment: Do you have a `.gitattributes` file in that repository?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with the contents of the `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: Your `.gitattributes` overrides your `core.autocrlf`, which is old and should not be relied upon.  Your `.gitattributes` specifies `text`, which means that CRLF conversion should be performed.  If you don't want that, set `-text`.